# TeamCity reuse artifact archive name

Tags: teamcity

I need to put several folders into artifact archive. Now I am doing it the following way:

```
P3Binaries/bin => build %env.BUILD_NUMBER%.zip!/bin
P3Binaries/DemoFiles => build %env.BUILD_NUMBER%.zip!/DemoFiles
```

But I don't want to duplicate archive name (a real name is even more complicated). Is there any way to store it to some variable an reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store this value in the build configuration parameter and reuse it.
[Defining and Using Build Parameters in Build Configuration](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration)